# Adding more IF condition to MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am updating two columns based on one column value using if else condition. If col1 is empty update col2 by adding random number. else update col1 by adding random number.

this is my query

```
UPDATE table SET 
col2=IF(col1='' OR col1 IS NULL, IFNULL(col2,0)+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1))), col2),
col1=IF(col1='' OR col1 IS NULL, col1, col1+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1)))) 
WHERE id >= $id
```

I want add one more condition to this that update only if col1 and col2 is less than allowed value(variable) i.e update col1 only when `col1<$allowed value` and update col2 only when `col2<$allowed value`

I have tried like this but it did not work

```
UPDATE table SET 
col2=IF(col1='' OR col1 IS NULL, IFNULL(col2,0)+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1))), col2),
col1=IF(col1='' OR col1 IS NULL, col1, col1+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1)))) 
WHERE id >= $id AND col1<$allowed_value AND col2<$allowed_value
```

If i remove any one condition from the query it works like

```
WHERE id >= $id AND col1<$allowed_value 
WHERE id >= $id AND col2<$allowed_value
```

I also tried this way but it didn't work

```
UPDATE table SET 
col2=IF(col1='' OR col1 IS NULL AND col2<$allowed_value, IFNULL(col2,0)+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1))), col2),
col1=IF(col1='' OR col1 IS NULL AND col1<$allowed_value, col1, col1+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1)))) 
WHERE id >= $id AND col1<$allowed_value AND col<$allowed_value
```

Sample data expected from query

```
col1 col2 allowed value
NULL NULL  1000        //update col2 only but only update if less than allowed value
20   NULL  1000        //update col1 only but only update if less than allowed value
NULL 20    1000        //update col2 only but only update if less than allowed value
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include those extra conditions in the `IF` statement, like this:

```
UPDATE table SET 
col2=IF((col1='' OR col1 IS NULL) AND IFNULL(col2,0)<$allowed_value, IFNULL(col2,0)+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1))), col2),
col1=IF(col1='' OR col1 IS NULL OR col1>=$allowed_value, col1, col1+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1)))) 
WHERE id >= $id
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0b11/1

Comment: Its not working, `col2` values gets updated to `null` when `col2` value becomes greater than `allowed value` and `col1` values keep on updating beyond `allowed value`.

Comment: I also tried this variation `(col1='' AND col2<$allowed_value) OR (col1 IS NULL AND col2<$allowed_value))` with your suggestion but same result ``

Comment: I did find a solution for my problem but your solution works as well thanks for taking time to reply.